# Cycles render showing up black

Tags: rendering, visibility

I am very new to blender (2.81) and have been following a number of different tutorials to produce this file.

Rendered images (cycles) were working fine but suddenly they now come up as black screens. I don’t understand as the rendered viewport view shows everything correctly!

I found a forum help post that gave a long list of things to try and fix this issues and I have attempted tthose I understood but none have worked.

Blend file:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13KHVJxB5VuuFE3hBDRyNraVbIl0MOxwn

If any of you kind folk could take a look and tell me what stupid mistake I have made I would be eternally grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one large object blocking your view.

In outliner go to *MEGACUBE > POOL > Cube.001* and disable the *Render Toggle.*
You also see the object in viewport if you toggle the Eye icon.

[image]

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhh .... doh! Thank you so much! Sorry for being a muppet! Live and learn!

Comment: It happens to all of us :). Feel free to mark the answer as accepted **✓**.

Comment: omg happened to me too. Was about to ask the same question as I luckily stumbled over this one. thanks!

Comment: @Christian Glad this post is still helpful after 4 years :))